# Error when trying to make a fat jar with maven in JavaFX on Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I have been trying to create a jar with maven and the maven-shade-plugin for my JavaFX project following this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyYb0GmtEX4.

I can create the jar file but when I run it, it gives me the error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.pleasework.com.example.pleasework.Main_1`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.pleasework.com.example.pleasework.Main_1`

I have already tried adding
`java --module-path /path/to/java-fx-libs/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml MyMainClass` to vm options but it just changes the error to `Error: Could not find or load main class Java`. Also, I have a second Main file that runs my first Main file which extends Application.

I am using IntelliJ and created my project through IntelliJ's built-in JavaFX project with Maven. I can run my project normally and it works fine, but when I try to run the shaded jar I generated through Maven's shade plugin I get these errors.

Here is my project structure: [image]

Here is my 2nd Main file

```
package com.example.pleasework;

public class Main_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloApplication.main(args);
    }
}
```

Here is my first main file

```
package com.example.pleasework;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PleaseWork</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PleaseWork</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.pleasework/com.example.pleasework.Main_1</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <includes>
                                <include>fun/n/learn/annotation/LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor.java</include>
                                <!--include dependencies required for LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor -->
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.pleasework/com.example.pleasework.Main_1</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `com.example.pleasework.com.example.pleasework.Main_1` looks suspicious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have to specify the main class without module name. Just use the fully qualified class name there. A fully qualified never contains a slash as it is not a path name. So in your case the fully qualified class name is including the XML tags around (the main class is used two times in your pom.xml and have to be corrected in both cases):

```
<mainClass>com.example.pleasework.Main_1</mainClass>
```

You can build the fully qualified class name yourself: use the string from the `package` declaration of the class you want to reference, add a dot and then write the class name from the class declaration and voila you have the fully qualified class name.

Comment: Looks like the user was prepending the module name and this is a modular app. Maybe? Personally I think fat jars are an anti-pattern, so I would never do this anyway. If you want to bundle an application use jpackage.

Comment: See the [openjfx maven plugin documentation](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin). The documentation demonstrates a mainClass with a / to after for the module name, followed by the package and class name. The shade plugin however will destroy modularity which is one reason to not use it.